# Microsoft Graph - Scoping Application Mail permissions

Tags: azure, email, graph, service

I am leveraging the graph api in powershell to automatically send emails to users.

This script is designed to run unattendedly, so i can not impersonate a user by logging in interactively.

In order to do so, i've created a service principal with application* permissions to the mail service of the tenant.
[image: Permissions]

However the mail permissions that can be assigned are far too large, as i don't want this service to be able to send mail as any user.

Is there a way to scope this permission such as my SP could only send mail with a specific service account that i would provision in azure ad, with the constraint of not being able to log in interactively prior to the script execution ?

Answer (score 0):

Having `Delegated` `Mail.Send` permissions would limit it to only the delegated user, which sounds like what you're after.

The dilemma though is that are running a PS script (a.k.a. no user involvement). You need user involvement to use Delegated, so yip...

You could contrive something like this:

- Setup `Delegated permissions` for sending mail
- Let the user log in once (somewhere) with your service principal, capturing their "refresh token"
- Let the PS script lookup the "refresh token" for the user to create an access token
- Use access token to send email "that specific" delegated user.

Unfortunately you won't be able to have "Delegated permissions" with no user interaction, so if that's the case, you're going to have to stick with the "wider" app permissions as you currently have.

Comment: I have inadvertently swapped the term delegated and application in my original post, sorry for that mistake, it's now fixed. About the solution you propose, do you know if, say a server reboot would force user interaction again ? I could try to store the token somewhere in memory for resilience, but it's probably not the best idea either (security wise) ... Thank you !

Comment: AAD refresh tokens are valid for 90 days, but if you keep using them, as far as I'm aware, you can keep it valid indefinitely. If you only want user interaction once off, then I would definitely persist it, either encrypted in a database or perhaps as a secret in Key Vault or something similar